# Using git rebase interactive to orchestrate series of git cherry-pick?

Tags: git, git-rebase, git-cherry-pick

git cherry-pick allows simple merges to be cherry-picked simply by indicating which of the merge parents should be used as the baseline.  For example:

```
git cherry-pick -m 1 1234abcdef
```

I have a bunch of commits that I want to cherry pick, a few of which may be merges, and others will not be.  I would like to be able to use git rebase to cherry-pick all these commits with something like this:

```
git rebase -i --onto myBranch myBranch
```

and put the pick list into the interactive file:

```
p 1234
p 3224
... a bunch more picks
p abcde
```

And, if git rebase encounters a merge in ones of those commits, I want to specify the equivalent of cherry-pick's `-m 1` option to indicate the change should be picked against the first parent.

I have tried a number of the merge-related options to rebase, but I always end up getting the error:

```
commit 3c4ffe04532 is a merge but no -m option was given.
```

(even if I specify -m to rebase.)

I realize I could write a script using cherry-pick, but I like the existing behavior `rebase -i` (it runs through the command list and pauses if it gets to something it can't handle).  I'd very much like to leverage that logic directly, but I haven't been able to figure out the right way to finesse rebase's `pick` command to fill in this gap.

Is there a way to get rebase to adopt cherry-pick's `-m #` behavior for `pick`?

To state my goal another way and help clarify the question - I want to use git-rebase's `--i` capability to coordinate a series of `git cherry-pick`s so that any merge conflicts in the process can be resolved manually and then the process can be managed with `--continue`, `--abort` and/or `--skip`.

This would be useful because a simple script consisting of:

```
git cherry-pick -m 1 e1bed15c97f3f
git cherry-pick -m 1 6b5e6060b0e99
....
git cherry-pick -m 1 1a625d6b45faa
```

is likely to abort with an error like this:

```
error: could not apply 6b5e6060b0e99... Implement Something... 
hint: after resolving the conflicts, mark the corrected paths
hint: with 'git add <paths>' or 'git rm <paths>'
hint: and commit the result with 'git commit'

d:\src>git cherry-pick -m 1   e1bed15c97f3f
error: Cherry-picking is not possible because you have unmerged files.
hint: Fix them up in the work tree, and then use 'git add/rm <file>'
hint: as appropriate to mark resolution and make a commit.
fatal: cherry-pick failed
```

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try to run the interactive rebase with the `-r` (`--rebase-merges`) option?

Comment: yes, I did; and to answer the question below I am on git v 2.31.0

Comment: Added to question above to hopefully clarify

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[mnestorov's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68978977/specify-merge-parent-for-rebase-pick#comment121910218_68978977) about using `--rebase-merges` is relevant here; consider it for the actual problem you're trying to solve (which you haven't really described: I'll note below where things seem to have gone off the rails).  It is possible you may be doing something that's a little too tough for `git rebase` as it stands today.  But I *think* you're doing exactly what `-r` is designed for.

If `-r` works, you're done.  If your Git is old, you may not have the `-r` / `--rebase-merges` option.  If so, the best answer is to upgrade your Git.

#### More about rebase

Let's talk more about rebase in general, starting with this:

> Is there a way to get rebase to adopt cherry-pick's `-m #` behavior for `pick`?

No: if there were, it wouldn't work anyway, at least not in general.  Here's why.

When you use the `-m` option here to "copy" a merge, you copy it into a non-merge, ordinary commit.  The `-m` option makes Git treat the merge commit as if it *were* an ordinary commit, with a single parent, and the `-m` flag tells it which parent to call "the" single parent.  But the *purpose* of a merge commit is, in general, to *combine work*, from two parents.<sup>1</sup>

Meanwhile, the purpose of `git rebase` is to repeatedly copy some commit(s), subsequently abandoning the original commits in favor of the new copies.  It's not possible to *copy* a merge commit—cherry-pick's `-m` doesn't do that; it produces an ordinary commit instead—so rebase normally *discards* merge commits.  I'll show *how and why this is the right thing*, for the way standard rebase works, below.

> ```
> git rebase -i --onto myBranch myBranch
> ```

Note that the argument to `--onto`, and the other argument that [the `git rebase` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase) calls *`upstream`*, default to being the same thing, so this is more simply written as:

```
git rebase -i myBranch
```

The *set of commits that are to be copied* by this action are limited to no more than those produced by:

```
git log myBranch..HEAD
```

That is, suppose we have the following, where newer commits are towards the right and we are currently on branch `topic`:

```
          G--H   <-- topic (HEAD)
         /
...--E--F--I--J   <-- myBranch
```

Running `git rebase myBranch`, with or without `--interactive`, tells Git: *First, list out those commits reachable from `HEAD` aka `topic`, minus any commits that are **also** reachable from `myBranch`.*  That causes Git to list out commits `G` and `H` internally.  These are the *candidates for copying*.

If these are the commits that *will* be copied in the end, and other simplifying assumptions hold, the result is going to be:

```
          G--H   [abandoned]
         /
...--E--F--I--J   <-- myBranch
               \
                G'-H'  <-- topic (HEAD)
```

where `G'` and `H'` are the copies of original commits `G` and `H`, with the copies having two important differences each:

- The parent of `G'` is `J`, instead of `F`.  The files within `G'` contain the same *changes* to `J` that `G` made with respect to `F`, so the *snapshot stored in `G'`* differs from that in `G`.
- The parent of `H'` is `G'`, instead of `G`, and its snapshot differs in much the same way.

That is, since each commit holds a *full snapshot*, we need the snapshots in the copied commits to differ from the snapshots in the originals.  The difference in the new snapshots is such that *comparing* `G'` vs `J` produces the same *diff*, more or less, as *comparing* `G` vs `F`.  And of course, the linkage—which in Git always goes backwards—is also different, so that the copies come after the last commit in `myBranch`.

---

<sup>1</sup>An *octopus merge*, if you have one, combines work from more than two parents, and the rare `-s ours` merge discards the contents of one parent entirely, so these special cases are even more special; in general, rebase should not be used on these.

---

#### What rebase doesn't do on purpose

Suppose that in our original two commits, `G` and `H`:

```
          G--H   <-- topic (HEAD)
         /
...--E--F--I--J   <-- myBranch
```

the *change* from `G` to `H` *is exactly the same* as the *change* from `I` to `J`.  For instance, both commits fix the spelling of the same misspelled word in the `README` file, and do nothing else.

When we run `git rebase myBranch`, Git still lists out commits `G` and `H`.  But it also looks at commits `I` and `J`, and for each commit, Git computes what it calls a *patch ID* (see [the `git patch-ID` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-patch-id)).  This patch ID tells Git: *Commit `H` is a duplicate of commit `J`.*  Git then *drops* commit `H` from the list of commits to copy.

So when we say that rebase lists out `myBranch..HEAD` to get candidate commits to copy, these are just *candidates*.  Some of these candidates are automatically eliminated, on purpose.  In this particular case, where only `H` is eliminated on purpose, the eventual result of the rebase would be:

```
          G--H   [abandoned]
         /
...--E--F--I--J   <-- myBranch
               \
                G'  <-- topic (HEAD)
```

Git basically believes that commit `H` is *already applied*.  So it drops it entirely.

There's a rather complicated dance that Git also does with something it calls the *fork point* code.  The goal of the fork-point code is to discover commits that *were deliberately dropped* and automatically drop them during rebasing.  This code usually does the right thing, though it can misfire.<sup>2</sup>  Neither the patch-ID nor the fork-point code seem to be biting you in this case, but there's one more big special case, which deserves its own section.

---

<sup>2</sup>The fact that it can misfire makes me think it's not necessarily the right default.  That applies to the "already applied upstream" patch-ID case as well.  In particular, interactive rebase really should include these commits on its instruction sheet, with the pre-selected action being "drop", and a comment as to why they're being dropped.  This is not the case today.

---

#### Merges

So far, the pictures we have drawn are simple.  But suppose our `topic` branch commits look like this:

```
                 I--J
                /    \
            G--H      M--N   <-- topic (HEAD)
           /    \    /
          /      K--L
         /
...--E--F--------------O--P   <-- myBranch
```

When we run:

```
git log myBranch..topic
```

we'll see commits `N` and `M`, and then—in some order—commits `I` through `L`, with `I` showing after `J` but randomly-ordered with respect to `K` and `L`, and with `K` showing after `L` but randomly-ordered with respect to `I` and `J`.  Then we'll see commit `H`, and then `G`, and that's the end of the list.

(If we add `--topo-order`, the order of the list gets more constrained.  The rebase code internally adds `--topo-order`.  We still don't know whether `L` or `J` will come first, but once we get one of those, we'll finish the entire row before going to the other row.  Without `--topo-order` we could see `N`, `M`, `L`, `J`, `K`, `I`, `H`, `G` instance.)

**Here's where your question goes off the rails a bit.**  The `git rebase` command will *automatically drop merge commit `M` entirely*, for two reasons:

- cherry-pick (and by extension, the old `git format-patch` / `git am` based method) *can't* copy a merge; and
- the result of a standard rebase *shouldn't* copy a merge anyway.

So you won't *have* a `pick` command for commit `M`.  To get one, you must be manually inserting your own, and this is a mistake.  To see why, let's look at how Git handles this without the `pick <hash-of-M>` in it, with a regular (non `--rebase-merges`) rebase.

The sequence starts by listing out the commits to copy.  Let's say they come out in this order, after `git rebase` carefully reverses them<sup>3</sup> while dropping merges: `G-H-I-J-K-L-N`.

If all goes well during the copying stages, the result will be:

```
                 I--J
                /    \
            G--H      M--N   [abandoned]
           /    \    /
          /      K--L
         /
...--E--F--O--P   <-- myBranch
               \
                G'-H'-I'-J'-K'-L'-N'  <-- topic (HEAD)
```

That is, `git rebase` has *flattened the merge away*.  But the purpose of merge `M` was to *combine the work* on the `I-J` and `K-L` branches.  We don't *need* that merge, because the process of copying `K` to `K'` was:

- for each change in the `H`-vs-`K` commit, make the same change to the contents taken from `I'`;
- now commit that as new commit `K'`.

That is, commit `K'` is based not on `H` or `H'`, but on `I'`.  It *already contains the other branch's work*.  Likewise, when Git copies `L` to `L'`, it does so onto a commit that *already contains the other branch's work*.  So there's no need for the branching.  The rebase operation simply flattens it away entirely.

---

<sup>3</sup>Remember, Git works backwards, so that the list always comes out with `N` first.  We need `N` last, so rebase reverses the list.

---

#### The `--rebase-merges` option

This idea of flattening away merges is not always a good one.  Sometimes it doesn't work very well.  Sure, a series like:

```
       I--J
      /
...--H
      \
       K--L
```

usually has relatively few changes on both branches, so that "flattening the branch away" is easy and goes well.  But what if the series has a ton of commits in each branch:

```
       o--o--...(1000 commits)...--o--tip1
      /
...--o
      \
       o--o--....................--o--tip2
```

In this case, the merge that merges the two tip commits might have a lot of work in it.  Flattening the merge away is impractical.

Or, maybe we just *like* having the merge present.  The merge represents something important, and we want future code archaeologists to *see* it.

Well, "copying" the merge is indeed impossible.  Cherry-pick's `-m` flag doesn't do that.  If we "copied" the merge with `cherry-pick -m` *after* flattening things:

```
                 I--J
                /    \
            G--H      M--N   <-- topic
           /    \    /
          /      K--L
         /
...--E--F--O--P   <-- myBranch
               \
                G'-H'-I'-J'-K'-L'  <-- HEAD
```

we'd just be re-introducing the changes we already got via either `I-J`, or via `K-L`.  To "copy" the merge *correctly*, we have to *form a branch* first:

```
                 I--J
                /    \
            G--H      M--N   <-- topic
           /    \    /
          /      K--L
         /
...--E--F--O--P   <-- myBranch
               \
                \      I'-J'   <-- temp-label-1
                 \    /
                  G'-H'
                      \
                       K'-L'   <-- temp-label-2, HEAD
```

Then we have to pick the correct branch *tip* to be the `HEAD` commit, and literally run `git merge` over again to make `M'`:

```
reset-to temp-label-1
merge temp-label-2
```

If the merge goes well, we'll now have:

```
                 I--J
                /    \
            G--H      M--N   <-- topic
           /    \    /
          /      K--L
         /
...--E--F--O--P   <-- myBranch
               \
                \      I'-J'  <-- temp-label-1
                 \    /    \
                  G'-H'     M'  <-- HEAD
                      \    /
                       K'-L'  <-- temp-label-2
```

We can now `pick hash-of-N` to make `N'`:

```
                 I--J
                /    \
            G--H      M--N   <-- topic
           /    \    /
          /      K--L
         /
...--E--F--O--P   <-- myBranch
               \
                \      I'-J'  <-- temp-label-1
                 \    /    \
                  G'-H'     M'-N'  <-- HEAD
                      \    /
                       K'-L'  <-- temp-label-2
```

and *then* we're done with this fancy rebase-that-re-does-the-merge, and can move the branch label `topic` and drop any temporary labels:

```
                 I--J
                /    \
            G--H      M--N   [abandoned]
           /    \    /
          /      K--L
         /
...--E--F--O--P   <-- myBranch
               \
                \      I'-J'
                 \    /    \
                  G'-H'     M'-N'  <-- topic (HEAD)
                      \    /
                       K'-L'
```

This is what `git cherry-pick --rebase-merges` does.  To achieve this result, it needs some extra commands and the ability to insert temporary labels.  (Note that there will also be a temporary label for `H'` since the sequence of cherry-picking operations has to reset `HEAD` there before copying `K` to `K'`.  You will see all this labeling and resetting in the instruction sheet, which needs to know when to make the various labels and where to move `HEAD` around.)

Comment: thanks for taking the time to describe rebase so thoroughly!  I appreciate the effort, but it seems the answer boils down to "git can't" do what I want.  "When you use the -m option here to "copy" a merge, you copy it into a non-merge, ordinary commit.... with a single parent."  <- This is in-fact exactly my goal.  I know the commit/branch history well enough to desire this behavior, and know that it should work for the commits in question and that none of the more complicated rebase scenarios you describe are the outcome I need. I want to use rebase to "script cherry-pick" as it were.

Comment: I added to the question above to hopefully clarify the actual problem I am trying to solve.

Comment: Rebase is—at least currently—the wrong tool for the updated question. Git's sequencer (which is what implements the rewritten-in-C rebase) can't handle this. You'll have to write your own script or program that runs `git cherry-pick` repeatedly, with the right options, and duplicates what the old interactive rebase script did, or modify Git's source code.